# Date histogram aggregation Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I want to filter and get data from elastic search. where I have tried **Date histogram aggregation** but its not solving my purposes.
I have data like:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "title":"Sample news",
      "date":"2020-09-17",
      "regulation":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"sample name",
            "date":"2020-09-17"
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"sample name 1",
            "date":"2020-09-18"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "title":"Sample news 1",
      "date":"2020-09-17",
      "regulation":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"sample name",
            "date":"2020-09-18"
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"sample name 1",
            "date":"2020-09-17"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to filter and get data like:

```
year: {
  month: {
   day: {
    news: int,
    regulations: int,
   }
 }
}
```

That means per day news and regulation count as a date Hierarchy.
I can achieve data like that:

```
        "2020-09-17" : {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-09-17",
          "key" : 1600300800000,
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        "2020-09-18" : {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-09-18",
          "key" : 1600387200000,
          "doc_count" : 0
        },
        "2020-09-19" : {
          "key_as_string" : "2020-09-19",
          "key" : 1600473600000,
          "doc_count" : 0
        },
```

using

```
GET /news/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "news_over_time": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "date",
        "calendar_interval": "day",
        "keyed": true,
        "format": "yyy-MM-dd"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it's not solving my purpose.
How can I do that using Elasticsearch and Elasticsearch dsl

**Expected response:**
Expected response:

```
2020: {
  09: {
   17: {
    news: 2,
    regulation: 2
   },
   18: {
    news: 0,
    regulation: 2
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you make it more clear? what the final response that you will get for the above example? the number of news in specific day?

Comment: 'regulation' is a nested object or multivalue field. Can you please share the index mapping ? Does regulations date also need to be taken into account or is it the news date only?

Comment: @CoderL I have updated my expected response. please have a look.

Comment: @SahilGupta regulation is a nested object and regulations date also needs to count regulation for a specific day.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't sure what your expected respone, but if you want to get the number of news for every day this is the request you looking for

```
GET /news/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "news_over_time": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "regulation.date",
        "calendar_interval": "day",
        "format": "yyy-MM-dd"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the news date and regulation date are 2 different fields & one of them belong to parent doc and other to nested doc. I am not completely sure that we can directly do what you are asking for (I myself is also exploring for the same). However, below query should also work for you.

```
GET news/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "news_over_time": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "date",
        "calendar_interval": "day",
        "keyed": true,
        "format": "yyy-MM-dd"
      }
    },"regulations_over_time":{
      "nested": {
        "path": "regulation"
      },"aggs": {
        "regulation": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "regulation.date",
            "calendar_interval": "day",
            "keyed": true,
            "format": "yyy-MM-dd"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**It will provide results in below form:**

```
"aggregations" : {
"regulations_over_time" : { //<=== Regulations over time based on regulationDate
  "doc_count" : 9,
  "regulation" : {
    "buckets" : {
      "2020-09-17" : {
        "key_as_string" : "2020-09-17",
        "key" : 1600300800000,
        "doc_count" : 5
      },
      "2020-09-18" : {
        "key_as_string" : "2020-09-18",
        "key" : 1600387200000,
        "doc_count" : 4
      }
    }
  }
},
"news_over_time" : { //<======= news over time based on news date
  "buckets" : {
    "2020-09-17" : {
      "key_as_string" : "2020-09-17",
      "key" : 1600300800000,
      "doc_count" : 2
    },
    "2020-09-18" : {
      "key_as_string" : "2020-09-18",
      "key" : 1600387200000,
      "doc_count" : 2
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

You can then merge these 2 stats together if required.

Comment: It's partially working. the results are coming side by side. Thank you.

Comment: I am not completely sure whether what u r asking is feasible or not. Please do accept the answer if it works for your case

Comment: I can't accept the answer because it's not the answer what I'm asking for.

Comment: Sure ... Thanks ... Please do let us know here if you got the answer what you are looking for.